# Weird dumpcore error while executing my program (C)

Tags: c, list, memory-management, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've made a program which reads numbers from a file and it should make a list with the read numbers .

Im not sure about the while(fscanf ... etc) . What kind of cycle can I make to read all the numbers till end of file ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
}Tnode;

typedef Tnode *Tlist;

Tlist CreateList();
Tnode *CreateNode(int x);
Tlist InsertAtEnd(Tlist list,int x);
void PrintList(Tlist list);
void PrintInfo(int nodeinf);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x,i;
    FILE *pf=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    assert(pf!=NULL);
    Tlist list;
    list=CreateList();

    while(fscanf(pf,"%d",&x)==1){
        list=InsertAtEnd(list,x);
    }
    PrintList(list);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
Tnode *CreateNode(int x){
    Tnode *newnode;
    newnode=malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    assert(newnode!=NULL);
    newnode->info=x;
    newnode->link=NULL;
    return newnode;
    }

Tlist CreateList(){
    return NULL;
}

Tlist InsertAtEnd(Tlist list,int x){
    Tnode *newnode,*tmp;
    newnode=CreateNode(x);
    tmp=list;
    //CASO IN CUI LA LISTA E' ANCORA VUOTA 
    if(tmp==NULL)
        tmp=newnode;
    else{//NEL CASO IN CUI LA LISTA NON E' VUOTA 
        while(tmp->link!=NULL){
            tmp=tmp->link;
        }
        tmp->link=newnode;
    }
    return list;
}

void PrintInfo(int nodeinf){
    printf("%d",nodeinf);
}

void PrintList(Tlist list){
    Tnode *node;
    node=list;
    while (node->link!=NULL){
        PrintInfo(node->info);
        node=node->link;
    }

return;
}
```

When i build it it gives me no mistakes . Then when I run it this is showed

```
0 [main] simulazione_1 669 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to simulazione_1.exe.stackdump

RUN FAILED (exit value 35.584, total time: 1s)
```

What's that error. What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Use a debugger.  Set a breakpoint, and step through your code.

Comment: the fact is the code is kinda long and i don't even know what's the problem . Like I dont know what the error stackdumpfile means

Comment: Your `InsertAtEnd` is returning `list` without assigning it. It will be (and remain) NULL. Please debug your code.

Comment: What you mean 5th line of the main list=InsertAtEnd ...

Comment: What will `InsertAtEnd` return? For the very first new node insertion.

Comment: I used the debug to check if the problem was InsertAtEnd . It gives me no errors but as soon as it gets out of the while cycle when it gotta print the list it gives me an error . I guess something is wrong with the printlist function

Comment: Haven't I just pointed you to the exact problem? Please re-read my last comment (before this one) and try to answer it.

Comment: If you are using a Linux system i'd recommend running your program with valgrind (i.e. valgrind your_program_name).  It will tell you exactly where the crash occurs.  From there it is easy to trace back to the root cause which is already covered in other comments.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I used that function in another program and it works properly i dunno if that's the problem

Comment: @PeriGiochi If you "don't even know what's the problem", run the program in a debugger until it crashes, then the debugger should show you at which point the system detected a problem. The debugger can show you the call stack, i.e. which functions called each other to get to this point. In the next run, set a breakpoint and single-step through the related functions. BTW `assert` should not be used to handle errors of `fopen` use something like `if(pf == NULL) { perror("fopen(file1.txt)"); return 1; }`.

Comment: effectively using the debugger i found out that the value of list never changes. I got whats the problem how do i fix it tho . @EugeneSh. you were prolly right .

Comment: @PeriGiochi Step through `InsertAtEnd` and you should see what is happening?

Comment: I restarted the application and my code works fine. The compiler or the runner was bugged apparently . Nothing wrong with the code. For whoever gets my problem fix the compiler lol

Comment: @PeriGiochi Computers tend to produce the same result under the same conditions. If your program works now, you must have changed something. The code in your question will behave in an undefined manner (i.e. it may crash), because you have two problems in `InsertAtEnd` and in `PrintList` which result in dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: i changed nothing i literally closed netbeans and opened it again and the code worked lol

Comment: @PeriGiochi Please, take the comments seriously. These are provided by the experts you are here for. Your code *is* broken. Do not rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding; `typedef Tnode *Tlist;`  it is a very poor practice to hide pointers in a `typedef`

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  For instance: `int main(int argc, char** argv) {` (due to the parameters not being used) will cause the compiler to output to warnings messages about unused parameters.  This can be fixed by using the other valid `main()` signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `Tlist CreateList();`  When writing the prototype for a function that does not take any parameters, always insert `void` between the parens.   I.E. `Tlist CreateList( void );`  Otherwise the compiler will produce code that can take any number of parameters

Comment: OT:  regarding: `void PrintInfo(int nodeinf)
{
    printf("%d",nodeinf);
}`  This will result in all the values being crammed together on a single line.  Suggest: `void PrintInfo(int nodeinf)
{
    printf("%d ",nodeinf);
}`  notice the space after the format specifier

Comment: OT: for readability, everywhere the posted code contains: Tlist replace with: `Tnode *`  -or- even better: `struct node *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first the error (you have *two* serious errors here):

First, you have made a mistake: you have guessed correctly that when the list is empty (just a `NULL` pointer) you'll have to change the initial pointer by a pointer to the first node, but when you code it, you don't consider it correctly and return the original passed pointer (which continues to point to `NULL`):

```
Tlist InsertAtEnd(Tlist list,int x){
    Tnode *newnode,*tmp;
    newnode=CreateNode(x);
    tmp=list;
    //CASO IN CUI LA LISTA E' ANCORA VUOTA 
    if(tmp==NULL)
        tmp=newnode;
```

you have to change the `list` pointer to return the correct value, as in:

```
        list=newnode;
```

or better:

```
        return newnode;
```

Second, in the print function, you need to continue the `while` loop, **not until the node has no `next` element,** (`while(node->link != NULL)`) (that will end the loop **before printing the last element**, and worse, this is what makes your program fail, as you are passing it an initial `NULL` pointer because you didn't populate correctly the list, and you try to access `node->link` when `node` itself is `NULL`, which is an error, and it's what makes your program to crash), so you have to check when the pointer iself is `NULL` (as in `while(node != NULL)`), leading to:

```
void PrintList(Tlist list) {
    Tnode *node = list;  /* idem. */

    while (node != NULL) {  /* why not use a for() loop here? */
        PrintInfo(node->info);
        node = node->link;
    }

    return;
}
```

or better:

```
void PrintList(Tlist list) {
    Tnode *node;

    for (node = list; node != NULL; node = node->link) {
        PrintInfo(node->info);
    }

    return;
}
```

---

## assert macro:

The `assert` macro **is a debugging macro**, you are doing bad use of it.  It shows you the line where the code fails (which is good), and the expression you pass to it (which is also good).  But it has a drawback you have not considered:  In production code, it is common to `#define NDEBUG 1` just to eliminate al the assertions you have made in the code (all the assertions are conditionally compiled).  This has one problem, by doing that, all the assertions in your code will dissapear magically, **but this includes all the tests you make in the arguments you pass to it** (and this is not good).  I've tried to rewrite all your assertions by a set of macros that will save typing, and also will make you possible to trace where in the code you have an error.  As there's no code in those macros to conditionally compile them in, you are safe that code will be on the final production code:

```
#define F(_fmt)  __FILE__":%d: " _fmt, __LINE__
```

this will expand:

```
    printf(F("Error: %s has not been opened\n"), file);
```

into:

```
    printf(__FILE__":%d: " "Error: %s has not been opened\n", __LINE__, file);
```

or, assuming that statement was in line 112 of file `pru.c`:

```
    printf("pru.c" ":%d: " "Error: %s has not been opened\n", 112, file);
```

that will result in (assuming file is `"File1.txt"`):

```
pru.c:112: Error: File1.txt has not been opened
```

In order to save you keystrokes, I have also defined an `ERR(fmt, ...)` macro to expand to a `fprintf(stderr, ...)` call.

---

## LEGIBILITY

You have to improve the legibility of your code, in order for it to be more readable.  It seems as if you were billed by each space you put in the code.

After all those modifications, your modified code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define F(_fmt) __FILE__":%d: "_fmt, __LINE__
#define ERR(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

typedef struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
}Tnode;

typedef Tnode *Tlist;

Tlist CreateList();
Tnode *CreateNode(int x);
Tlist InsertAtEnd(Tlist list, int x);
void PrintList(Tlist list);
void PrintInfo(int nodeinf);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x,i;
    char *file_name = "file1.txt";

    FILE *pf=fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (!pf) {
        ERR(F("%s: %s\n"), file_name, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Tlist list = CreateList();  /* it's good to initialize in declarations */

    while(fscanf(pf, "%d", &x) == 1) {
        list = InsertAtEnd(list, x);
    }
    PrintList(list);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Tnode *CreateNode(int x)
{
    Tnode *newnode = malloc(sizeof(Tnode));  /* better initialize in declaration */

    if (!newnode) {
        ERR(F("malloc: %s\n"), strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newnode->info = x;
    newnode->link = NULL;

    return newnode;
}

Tlist CreateList()
{
    return NULL;
}

Tlist InsertAtEnd(Tlist list, int x)
{
    Tnode *newnode = CreateNode(x),  /* idem. */ 
          *tmp = list;

    // CASO IN CUI LA LISTA E' ANCORA VUOTA
    if(tmp == NULL) {
        return newnode;  /* return here, you have nothing else to do */
    }

    // NEL CASO IN CUI LA LISTA NON E' VUOTA
    while(tmp->link != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->link;
    }
    tmp->link = newnode;

    return list;
}

void PrintInfo(int nodeinf) {
    printf("%d\n", nodeinf);  /* you lacked a \n here */
}

void PrintList(Tlist list) {
    Tnode *node = list;  /* idem. */

    while (node != NULL) {  /* why not use a for() loop here? */
        PrintInfo(node->info);
        node = node->link;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: under  `LEGIBILITY` suggest also mentioning the undesirability of  hiding a pointer via a `typedef` statement

Comment: @user3629249, definitely your point is true.  But as this is clearly an academic question, I preferred not to burden my response with a bunch of details that are more focused to a more advanced level.  IMHO that's one of those, so I need to apologize you for not including it.  Despite of it, your comment is a best place to point this out.  Thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

The function `InsertAtEnd` is invalid. When initially the list is empty then the function returns NULL because the pointer `list` is not changed in the function.
It is the pointer `tmp` that is changed.

Using your approach the function can look the following way

```
Tlist InsertAtEnd( Tlist list, int x ) 
{
    Tnode *newnode = CreateNode(x);

    if ( list == NULL )
    {
        list = newnode;
    }
    else
    {    
        Tnode *tmp = list;

        while ( tmp->link != NULL )
        {
            tmp = tmp->link;
        }

        tmp->link = newnode;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Also the function `PrintList` is also incorrect. It should be defined the following way

```
void PrintList( Tlist list )
{
    for (  Tnode *node = list; node != NULL; node = node->link )
    {
        PrintInfo(node->info);
    }
}
```